# XSL to subset a set of records based on a file of xml records

Tags: xslt

I have a large XML file and another small XML file with names that match one of the attribute values of some of the large XML file. I would like to create a subset of records of the large XML file, using the small one. My XSL attempt is something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:t="http://www.xyz.com/xml/Fixit" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="t:Fixit[.//t:Name[(@OrganisationName!=document('single_include.xml')//OrganisationName)]]"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My small XML file called "single_include.xml" is like this

```
<ListOfOrganisationName>
<OrganisationName>
The first organisation
</OrganisationName>
<OrganisationName>
The second organisation
</OrganisationName>
</ListOfOrganisationName>
```

It seems to work for the first record only. Any ideas?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you include a (small) sample of your large XML, together with your expected output? Thanks!

Comment: This question is quite vague. Please, *edit* the question and provide a *small* XMLDoc1 (what you call the "large XML file) and also provide the exact wanted result. Also, explain the requirements for the transformation. It isn't clear what you mean by "subset of records" and what you mean by "that match".

Answer (score 0):

The inner predicate in your "exclusion" template

```
(@OrganisationName!=document('single_include.xml')//OrganisationName)
```

is true if there is *any* `OrganisationName` in `single_include.xml` that is not equal to the current element's `OrganisationName` attribute.  This would exclude "The second organisation" because there is an `OrganisationName` in the filtering file ("The first organisation") to which it is not equal.  Instead, you probably want

```
not(@OrganisationName=document('single_include.xml')//OrganisationName)
```

which is true only if there is *no* `OrganisationName` in `single_include.xml` that is equal to the current element's `OrganisationName` attribute.  The XPath spec makes this point in [section 3.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) where it says that

> **NOTE:** If `$x` is bound to a node-set, then `$x="foo"` does not mean the same as `not($x!="foo")`